# Contextual expression and Get/Got It

Tags: idioms, expressions, phrasal-verbs

**First context**

If I taught something to my students and wanted to check whether they understood me or not, what should I say ?

**second context**

If I were to ask them whether they are following me or not, How should I ask?

Also tell me the usage about the following expressions :

> Do you get it ?
>   Did you get it ?
>   Got it ?
>   Get it ?
>   Did you get me ?

Please make them clear to me.

Comment: I don't think most people will give a useful answer to such a question. Either they got it and can truthfully answer "yes" or they didn't get it without really knowing and answer "yes", anyway. Just a small number will know that they didn't get it and answer "no".

Comment: First context: Do  you get this or Did you get this? Second context: Are you getting this? To mean: Are you understanding what is being taught to you? Got it is too short for your contexts.

Comment: @Lambie What could be other expressions for both contexts, would you tell me ?

Comment: @yubraj I already told you how to phrase it in the two contexts. To get something means to understand something. I don't see where there is any problem with that. Do you get this? = Do you understand this?

Comment: Ok, Thanks @Lambi , About "Get/Got it", It's only about the difference between present and past tense not about their meanings ?

Comment: @yubraj -- yes both get it and got it mean the same thing and it is only a difference of tense. Many English speakers will not notice the tense as long as this expression is used in the context you've used.

Comment: There *might* be a useful question here if it could be narrowed down to a potential difference between, say, *Do you get it?* and *Did you get it?* But even that would probably be better explored with something like *What do you want?* as opposed to *What did you want?* I think as it stands the question looks like either proofreading or an open-ended request for *What kind of things do native speakers normally say in this situation?*, which is essentially a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 5):

**First:**

- Does everyone understand?
- Got it? Get it?
- Did everyone follow my explanation?
- Are there any questions?
- Did this make sense to you?

**Second**

All of your examples work if you are speaking to students comfortable in speaking and understanding English. If you doubt that they do understand, ask them questions on what they have learned. A small quiz at the end of a lesson tells the teacher whether or not they were understood. It is the teacher's job to make the lesson understandable. If your students do not understand knowing that they don't 'get it' as quickly as possible is important.

Comment: Your examples are excellent, your post is excellent. However, I'm going to have to downvote you for pedagogical reasons :(

Comment: @ Araucaria I do not understand.  Why do you disagree with my pedagogical methods? I was a teacher for over thirty years, so I am interested in your reasoning. This is not about the downvote.

Comment: @ Araucaria As I said in my answer, IF you doubt a student's understanding, you ask questions. I was not here to instruct anyone on the details of how a teacher teaches. Frankly, I think teachers do best when they bring their own tools to the classroom. You have a method that works for you --  even if I would not use it.

Comment: Ok, so I think you think this is just my personal opinion. It's not, though! It's derived from lots of observation and research (not mine!). If you are observed by the British Council  and you ask that question it will show up in your report as a black mark in the teaching report, and if you do it on a CELTA or DELTA course, you'll get reprimanded and it could well contribute to your failing your observation. As a Director of Studies, if a teacher persisted in doing this, I'd have to take remedial action. [Perhaps see here](http://busyteacher.org/18236-how-to-check-comprehension-6-tips.html).

Comment: I've added a community wiki post answer on here which links to various webpages dealing with this question, including one from the British Council. Hope they're interesting/useful. They will explain better than I can why "Do you understand?" does not work.

Comment: @Araucaria Oh ! Thanks for that. And for providing a useful wepage. I upvoted you. Actually I was confused because I didn't know how to understand if students understood me or not. So, I wanted to ask my students by questioning "Got/Get it ?" It would help me to understand them.

Comment: I'm talking about teaching in general. Especially at schools.

Comment: @yubraj that would have been good information to have had in your question. How about adding now for future readers? Languages are taught differently and Araucaria assumed you meant the subject of teaching English..

Comment: @Araucaria You and I both made assumptions based on the post. I taught special education for 34 years to ages 4-11. Asking questions and quizzing were some of the methods that worked. I would assume that any teacher simply asking "Do you understand?" to a room without checking that the students did understand, isn't a teacher. However the OP was about how to say "Get it?" So that was why we all answered that question.

Comment: @WillowRex Yes, I think you're right. I also think we pretty much agree.

Comment: I'm not specific. I'm talking about teaching in an English school in general. Ok, I would be benfitied to know about teaching ESL Students too. But I'm not that skilled or experienced yet to teach ESL Students. I'm still learning English to get to that level, though.

Answer (score 5):

> Do you get it? Did you get it?

Are pretty much interchangeable. One is present tense, the other is past tense.

> Got it?

This is more terse. I would avoid using this unless you are upset with someone. It is sometimes considered rude, and would be used if you are repeating something multiple times to someone who had trouble understanding you.

> Get it?

I would also avoid this one. This is commonly used when someone has told a joke, and no one laughs. The person who told the joke might ask "Get it?" to ask if people understood or "got" why the joke was funny.

> Did you get me?

More casual, I would mostly use this if I was unsure as to whether or not I was *heard* rather than understood.

I think for most purposes, you could ask "Did you understand me?" or, "Did everyone understand the lesson?" as those are more polite.

Comment: I think stackexchange ethics is to suggest improvements in a comment instead of downvoting, only downvoted if you feel relevant changes have been ignored. Feel free to suggest an edit to my post if you also have an issue with my formatting.

Comment: I think the terseness of "Got it?" is entirely dependent on mood and tone of voice.

Comment: Araucaria downvoted you (I think) because s/he thinks the OP was talking about teaching English and because they have a difference of opinion with you (us) about how teachers should teach. Not a good reason, imo, but that is apparently 'why'. We all have the prerogative to downvote -- for any reason we choose.

Comment: I'm talking about teaching in general. It might be teaching in English language in school. And you know, there isn't only an English text book like ESL Teaching. Everybody knows that  Many subjects are taught in school.

Comment: @yubraj Generally speaking, that's a pretty good all round general teaching principle. When I teach phonetics at university, for example, I try not to use those types of phrase, because the same principles apply. Difficult to do though! I'm not always successful. Again, you can use different types of question to check Ss' understanding in pretty much any type of classroom.. "What would happen if ...?" - "Is this the same as xyz?" - "Does it go before or after the + sign?" etc etc :-)

Comment: Could you suggest me some more class room/teaching vocabulary or phrases so that I would use them in teaching. To be honest, I'm gonna teach in a school. I haven't teached before.

Comment: @yubraj Oh, exciting! :-) What are you going to teach? (I'm asking so I know what kind of language might be helpful for you!)

Comment: Language is English in teaching but the subjects might be different depending on grade. I'm gonna teach in an English school up to grade 10. But the language is English as it's an English school.

Comment: @WillowRex it's a good idea to suggest how to improve someone's post, or mention if an error exists, but... you don't *know* who DVed this post, and you don't know *why* they DVed an answer. And Aracauria is a bloke/dude/guy :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA at one point Araucaria, said s/he did and OP asked why. So I explained it. Should I delete?

Comment: @WillowRex I did not know that. OK, I've just read the conversation between yourself and Araucaria underneath your answer, things are clearer now. As for the question "Do you understand" by itself in a *language* lesson, that question is not very useful, but it can slip out, I'd call it a venial sin- No one will get hurt! If the teacher and students rapport is good, a teacher will sense if a class have grasped the essentials or not.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The OP was not teaching a language lesson -- and did not say so, and was asking a specific question -- the one we all answered. I think that is why there was a question of why there was a DV. However, in teaching we always have to know what we are asking. It is pointless to ask if everyone understands without knowing that the students will admit to not understanding. So in the end, Araucaria and I agreed, we just misunderstood each other initially.

Answer (score 3):

First rule of (language) teaching:

- Never ask your students if they understand!

First off, they will often be too embarrassed to say 'no', or too tired, or just not want to disrupt the lesson (as they see it). Secondly, they may think they understand, but in actual fact not understand at all. Thirdly, most of the time, what's really happening is that the teacher is subconsciously seeking approval from their students.

You need to use concept checking questions instead.

So, for example, you've just done an exercise where students have been reading a text with the verb *blow*. There's a matching exercise where your students have matched the word *blow* with a definition *spend a lot of money on something*.

Suppose you ask them: *Do you understand?*. They all say 'Yes'... What have you found out? Nothing! You have absolutely not one iota of evidence that they understood at all (which doesn't mean that they *haven't* understood - it just means that you don't know). Here's  what you might  do instead:

In order to find out if your students have really got  the meaning of this verb we need to think about what problems or misunderstandings they might have. This is crucial, because it will inform you about what kind of checking you might need to do. So you'd want to think about the **meaning**, the **form / usage** and then the **pronunciation** to give you a guide, and then check them (in that order) using questions.

So, in terms of meaning, one problem students could have with that definition might be that *blow* doesn't just mean to spend a lot of money on something. It means to spend your money on something unimportant. If you blow your money you don't have anything substantial and important afterwards. To blow your money is to be frivolous. It's a negative thing. So you might want to use the following concept checking scenario:

- Last week I had ten thousand Euros in the bank. Yesterday I spent all of it on a Masters degree at Oxford University. Did I blow my money?

The answer of course should be *no*. But even if they say *no*, you don't have anything to check that against. So you'll need to ask "Why not?". You might want to contrast that with a different scenario. So a next question might be:

- Ok, so last week I had ten thousand Euros in the bank. I spent five thousand Euros at the casino, three thousand Euro's going to expensive nightclubs, and I spent two thousand Euros on a taxi from London to Edinburgh because I didn't want to get the train. Did I blow my money?

Of course, you will want to ask "Why?" after they give you the answer "Yes!".

An alternative way of checking their understanding is also very simple and less teacher-focused. You can simply say: "Tell me about the last time you blew some money on something". The phrase "Give me an example ..." is worth a billion "Do you understand?"s. You will understand very well from your student's answer whether they really understand or not. You may also find out whether they intuitively get the grammar or not and whether they have any pronunciation issues with the word.

Of course, you might also want to explicitly check whether they get the grammar. So you might want to board something like this

> Yesterday (BLOW) / meal with my friends / $100.

And then say "Can you give me a sentence?". Of course what you are checking is whether they give you a sentence with $100 as the Direct Object and use the preposition *on* before the noun phrase "meal with my friends" (as opposed to *in* or *with*).

Lastly you might want to check if they understand exactly how the word should sound, and if they are able to physically pronounce the word correctly. I'll let you think about this one. Here are two questions/sentences you could use for checking this:

- Repeat: "I blew all my money on fast food"
- Do you understand how to pronounce this word?

Which one do you think will work best?

[Well, exactly!]

Comment: Where did the OP say s/he was teaching language?

Comment: I'm confused to have found the answers which differ from one another.

Comment: @yubraj  Differing answers are the nature of a site like this. Perhaps some of us misunderstood your question. What do you not understand about the answers? It is fine for people to have different methods and experience. YOU get to decide which answer(s) works for you.

Comment: @WillowRex They didn't, but they did say "If I taught something to my students ...", which suggests that they may, but more importantly asks about a teaching scenario ... :-)

Comment: Okay, so then I will just disagree with you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I don't completely understand your question, especially the part about contexts, but here's what I would say in a classroom situation to make sure everybody in the class is rolling on the same page and no one is left behind:

> Is everything clear so far?
>   Are you following me so far?
>   So far so good?

As for the second question about different get expressions, they all seem fine to me except the last one.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how big an idea you're trying to explain. The bigger or stranger the idea, the less terse you want to be. If you're taking breaks to check and see if everyone understands, try something like

> Make sense?
>
> You follow?
>
> Any questions?

However, if you're explaining an entire lesson and then asking, you want to be a bit more forgiving in your language. If you expect people to have questions because it's confusing or too much to easily digest, try something along these lines

> I know that was a lot. Does everyone understand?
>
> If you have any questions, don't be afraid to ask.

It comes down to expectations. Like I said, the bigger the idea, the longer the confirmation. On the flip side, if it's something simple or easy to grasp, you can be more terse. As an example

> Turn left, then right, and then count to three. Got it?

*Got it?* Almost means *Did you hear me?* in this context. You're not asking if they *understood* you, because you have zero doubt they can understand the difference between left and right. You're asking if they *got* the message. This is why it's normally considered rude to use *Get it/ Got it* in conversation. Explaining Quantum Mechanics to someone and asking if they *got it* would be offensive because you're basically saying

> It's so simple to me that I don't even need to ask if you understood, because anyone could make sense of it if they just *got* the message.

Since they clearly don't understand non-locality or chromodynamics on the first go, you're calling them an idiot by saying *got it*? That's not to say it's rude all of the time, though. If you're giving someone a number or code over the phone, you can say

> Yeah, It's verification-code W359-G581-WISE3159. Got it?

Again, you're not asking if they understood the number 3. You're asking if they *got* the message. In fact, it's almost polite in this context to  say *got it*, because you're making sure they have the correct information.

Comment: @UIdalexThanks for suggesting such useful phrases and sentences.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quote from Laura Greenwood:

> > - “Right?” “Does that make sense?” “Do you have it?” “OK?”
>
> It does not matter how a teacher phrases: “Do you understand?” All of these questions are ineffective attempts at checking meaning with ESL/EFL students.

Here are some useful webpages to understand why these questions don't work. Some of them also explain what you can ask or do instead if you need to check your students' understanding:

- [English teachers, are you asking the right questions?](https://www.britishcouncil.org/voices-magazine/english-teachers-are-you-asking-right-questions)
- [Do You CCQ? Using Concept Checking Questions in the ESL Classroom](http://www.bridgetefl.com/do-you-ccq-using-concept-checking-questions-in-the-esl-classroom/)
- [Why You Should Never Ask 'Do You Understand'](http://busyteacher.org/18236-how-to-check-comprehension-6-tips.html)
- [What do teachers mean by "Did you understand?"](https://www.quora.com/What-do-teachers-mean-by-Did-you-understand)