# Can the phrase "I think I got it thanks" offend people?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, sarcasm

I have searched and read some related questions from this site, here are some of the topics: [discussion 1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/42048/377789), [discussion 2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/17488/110852), [discussion 3](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/229421/110852), [discussion 4](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/115286/110852), [discussion 5](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4594/110852) and [discussion 6](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/259158/110852). However, none of them *firmly* answers my question.

I was posing a question to someone and after they answered my question, I said "I think I got it, thanks". Somehow, though subconsciously I said this, (actually I typed this, since I commented) though I shouldn't have said that. To me, I sound as if I was being sarcastic like, in equivalent, I meant to say "I don't need your answer anymore because I've already figured out the meaning of that word before you're going to tell me".

Is it just me being overthinking or that phrase really can offend people? Besides, some people also say that this is ungrammatical and should be avoided, but some people also differ. If so, should I avoid this phrase to say that I understand and thanks to any people who answer my questions? What grammatical phrase I should just use to show respect and say that I have understood because they told me without seeming to sound I'm being sarcastic?

Comment: Sarcasm / rudeness is primarily governed by ***context*** and ***delivery / diction*** (how you *say* it), rather than the words themselves. Speaker could be expressing gratitude for having had something explained, OR annoyance because addressee is *still* explaining something that was obviously and completely covered by his first sentence on the subject several minutes ago. Where speaker has politely listened to irrelevant additional details for some time, but is getting seriously fed up with addressee's ongoing monologue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not! I read it and found no sarcasm or evidence that this could possibly offend someone. This response can be used in many cases when one understands what someone is trying to say. There is no need for any alternative phrase, but here are some:

> I understand now, thanks!
>
> Oh I get it now! (Informal)

Answer (score 1):

That's a perfectly good response in informal English.

It means "I believe that I understand" and (if you are being asked to do something) "I will do it."

There is no sarcasm.

<sub>I don't understand why you think this could be in anyway offensive:</sub>



> I was posing a question to someone and after they answered my question, I said "I think I got it, thanks". [...] I sound as if I was being sarcastic like, in equivalent, I meant to say "I don't need your answer anymore because I've already figured out the meaning of that word before you're going to tell me".




<sub>That doesn't make sense! You said "I got it" *after* they answered. So why would you suppose it means "I figured it out *before*"?</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not the response "I think I got it, thanks!" sounds offensive depends on the circumstances and on the tone you choose. It could be a sincere "thank you", or it could be meant to stop the other one talking / repeating themselves. In a chat the tone could be marked by a thumbs up icon, e.g., in the positive case. Expressing a negative tone could possibly look like "I think I got it ...".